# Counting the number of binary heaps created with N elements with duplicite numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binary, recursive-algorithms

A heap is a tree with numbers where a parent of a number must be equal or lower than the number itself. ([This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcE9m.gif).)

I know how to count the number of possible heaps with distinct elements such as `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`.
But if I wanted to count the number of heaps looking like this: `{1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`, where 4 is two times...?

How do I rewrite **f(N) = (N−1 C L) * f(L) * f(R)** *(used to count possibilities from first sample)* to be able to work with duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the general answer and I don't know what your formula means. But in your second case, the only difference is that you can always swap the positions of the two $4$ and you'll get the same heap, whereas before you only could swap $3$ and $4$ when they where not linked, and the heap was then different. So if $N_1$ and $N_2$ denote the number of heaps in the two cases and if $R$ is the number of heaps in the first case where $3$ and $4$ are linked, then you get:

$$ N_2 = R + \frac{N_1-R}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. N in my formula = whole binary heap. L = left "wing" of the heap, R = right "wing". It all works recursively. For example:
f(4) = (4−1 C 2) * f(2) * f(1) =  (4−1 C 2) * (2−1 C 1) * 1 * 1
What do you mean by N2?

Comment: $N_2$ is what you are looking for: the number of heaps with elements from the second list (with two $4$)

Comment: Do you always have at most two branches?